# Probability that the call will be answered at time $t$ is given by $f(t)$. Find the median waiting time for the call.

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, statistics, definite-integrals

$$f(t) =  \begin{cases}    0 & \text{if $t < 0$ } \\    0.2e^{-t/5}       & \text{if $t\geq 0$}   \end{cases}$$.

$ $

Find the median waiting time for the call.

$ $

I cannot understand what is the meaning of median waiting time.

I know what is median in statistics.

Comment: That is not the probability that the call will be answered at time $t$. If the random variable $T$ is the time at which the call is answered, $f(t)$ is the density function of $T$. So if $F(t)$ is the probability that $T\le t$, then $f(t)$ is the derivative of $F(t)$. The probability that the call is answered in the time interval $t$ to $t+h$, where $h$ is small, is approximately $hf(t)$.

Comment: thanks, i confused myself with probability density function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that "median" means "50th percentile", meaning that you have a 50% chance of falling under the median.

Also note that $\int_0^\infty f(t) dt$ = 1, so the function you wrote is a probability density function. This means that $P(t<T) = \int_0^T f(t) dt$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: The median $a$ for a random variable $X$ with density is the unique number satisfying
$$
P(X\leq a)=P(X\geq a)=\tfrac12.
$$